# Making a txt file using excel sheet data

Tags: python, csv, txt

[excel image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuVet.png)

[txt image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9QsI.png)

I am a biology student and have no experience in coding. I want to make [txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ZElEq9VCDj5pqxWEsAPiaJTDc14lYJA/view) files from specific data from [excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S55wlHGXLQg0R88kxB14h1U1fOZAn3dM/view) files. The data in the txt file should be in the format given in the txt file where

```
center_x = data from center_x and pocket 1 (col 7, row 2)
center_y = data from center_y and pocket 1 (col 8, row 2)
center_z = data from center_z and pocket 1 (col 9, row 2)
```

and

```
size_x = 60
size_y = 60
size_z = 60

energy_range = 10
```

How can I make a python script which can do this for 1000 excel files?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you copy paste the header of the text file and the excel file if it's csv, otherwise an image would be great. Because from where I'm connected I can't get access to google drive ;)

Comment: first do it for single file and put code in function -ie. `my_function(filename)` - and later use `for`-loop to execute this function for many files on list.

Comment: added the images for the excel anf txt files.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code. First you have to read data from file using i.e. `pandas.read_excel()` or `pandas.read_csv()`, later create one string with all needed lines and later write it in file.

Comment: do you want all values in one file or values from every excel in separated file?

Comment: generating only one txt file from one excel file and then do this for every excel file in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do it for single file and put code in function which get filename as argumetn - ie. `function(filename)` - and later use `for`-loop to execute it for many filenames on list.

```
import pandas as pd

def function(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python')
    #print(df.columns)
    
    row = df[ df['name'] == 'pocket1' ]
    x = row['center_x'][0]
    y = row['center_y'][0]
    z = row['center_z'][0]
    
    #print(x, y, z)
    
    text = ""
    text += f"center_x = {x}\n"
    text += f"center_y = {y}\n"
    text += f"center_z = {z}\n"
    text += f"\n"    
    text += f"size_x = 60\n"    
    text += f"size_y = 60\n"    
    text += f"size_z = 60\n"
    text += "\n"
    text += "energy_range = 10\n"
    
    print(text)
    
    with open(filename + '.txt', 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(text)
        
# --- main ---

#import os
#all_filenames = os.listdir()

#import glob
#all_filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')

all_filenames = ['structure.pdb_predictions.csv']

for filename in all_filenames:
    function(filename)
```

Comment: I got some problems in windows but it worked in linux! thanks a lot for the help. I am not able to upvote because of new account but thank you for your contribution!!